# How to reverse the effect of -*-user-select:none;?

Tags: css

I have 2 CSS files linked in one page.

The first file contains formatting for the main site, and the second contain formatting for a 'popup' iframe.

The first file has 2 lines, that disallow selection on the page:

```
body {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

I need some sort of value instead of `none`, or some different property to put in the second css file, so the user can select inside the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://help.dottoro.com/lcrlukea.php for all possible values. Note that some values are vendor prefixed at the moment. Default is `user-select: text`.